# Searching for a word and then returning a number or word in the same line

Tags: java, algorithm, search

I have a program that takes user input and stores each word in an arrayList, and then searches for each word in an external file. What I want to do from here is return another word (which is in another arrayList) or the price value **in the same line as the first searched for word.**

For example:

```
Here is my user input: Tuna

Here are my associated words in another arrayList: (seared, chunky, shredded)

Here are lines in my file: the cost of seared tuna is $1 per tin. Contains brine.
                           the cost of shredded tuna is $50 per packet
```

I then want my program to search each line for tuna and then print out:

```
Seared $1
Shredded $50
```

For my program to do this I need it to understand that the word **seared** is in the first line that tuna appears and that the monetary value in this line is $1. Then to repeat the process for the next line.

The main thing that I need to know is if a buffered reader makes a distinction between separate lines and if I can search each line separately for my words in the arrayList and the monetary values.

My code that I use for searching is below. So far it only searches a file for a word and then returns the location of that word.

```
while((strLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null){
  for(String list: listOfWords){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(list);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine1);

    int start = 0;
    while (m.find(start)) {
      System.out.printf("Word found: %s at index %d to %d.%n", m.group(), m.start(), m.end());
      start = m.end();
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this is easier to understand.

Comment: I think you should use case insensitive search also I would use `contains` or `indexOf` method instead of regex: `strLine1.toLowerCase().contains(list.toLowerCase())`.

Comment: Can you explain what is actual question is? It seems you know how to read files line by line and search words in lines. What is your doubts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you be more precise on what you want to return, format of external files and what you want to display?

Regarding your code
you can use str1.contains(str2) method inside String class to check whether user entered word is there in the line or not instead of using matcher as there is no regexp here.

If user enters multiple words then you can have a loop for that.

Comment: i have adjusted my question to try and explain everything better. The problem is the format of the files can vary, but I think that using str1.contains(str2) will work. I'll try it and let you know. Thanks

Comment: BufferedReader makes distinction of lines and reads line by line. Please try it by your self and let us know if you still have any problems. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think if you want to search prices in the lines you could look for the "$" symbol and then extract numbers.

Comment: Was thinking about that the problem is to get the program to know that it came from the same line. Need to resolve that before i can implement your idea. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You seem to know how to read lines and how to iterate through them, that's good. Now all you need to do is check each line if it contains the word "tuna" and if it does replace the "tuna " string with "" and you got your Seared $1 or the Shredded $50.

Comment: i have changed my question to make it more clear. Unfortunately i've already tried your option before with no success as the lines are all formatted differently, with the only constant being that one of my words in the arrayList is in the line and there is a price value(See adjusted question). Think that another user has posted something that might work though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've said:
"The main thing that I need to know is if a buffered reader makes a distinction between separate lines and if I can search each line separately".

But readLine() does read separate lines which devided by linefeeds(\n). So you can process these lines separetely. Sorry if I didn't understand your question...

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to confirm if it does. Someone has sent in something that I can use to incorporate my search with my arrayList, so I'm trying that out when I get a chance